# Jenkins Git Clone Behaviour Modification for each build

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way we can modify the git behaviour, whenever the job is cloning the repository, we need to timestamp to the folder name.

The intention is, I have a list of jobs in a jenkins view which has the same repository and whenever I try to bulk build the view, it is having a lot of collusion because the repository folder is same.

So ideally, when the Jenkins GIT plugin is cloning the repository, I need to add a timestamp   so that the folder is unique and the job is built with proper information.

Edit: Information on the type of job in jenkins
I'm using a Jenkins FreeStyle Project

Comment: Do you try to use a custom workspace ? In configuration general tab, advanced options : Use custom workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the same workspace for all jobs.
You can configure the `Workspace Root Directory` so that the workspace is unique for each job:
`Jenkins` -> `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System` -> `Home directory` -> `Advanced` -> `Workspace Root Directory`

> The value should normally include ${ITEM_ROOTDIR} or
> ${ITEM_FULL_NAME}, otherwise different jobs will end up sharing the
> same workspace.

If you still want to use the same workspace for all jobs, you can configure each job to checkout to a different subdirectory of the workspace instead of the workspace root: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-checkout-to-a-sub-directory